# What is the shortest form to indicate a multiplication factor / a count / a number of available systems in a table heading?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I have to create a table similar to the one seen in the attached images. The table describes several systems with different parameters like volume etc.

In the second column I would like to give the number how often these systems exist in a certain plant. Unfortunately I have to keep the columns as short as possible to have enough space for the parameters.

What would be the shortest form in English to be used in the heading to indicate that the number/count of systems is meant. Are there any common abbreviations?

[image: Example of table]

[image: Example of table]

Comment: **Count**, **obs** (observations), **num** (number) might be used. What is the context is it a set number known/calculated beforehand or an observed number?

Comment: I agree that **number**, **num**, **No.**, or **#** might be appropriate.  I don't really understand how "how often available" can be expressed as a single number, but maybe that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *# avail*

would be commonly understood to mean *number available.*

> *Qty*

Is a common abbreviation for *quantity.*